# Capture some of the iphone screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, screen, cgimage

i am using this code to capture my screen.

```
        CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

this code take all of the screen.
 i need only some of it... `CGRect rect = CGRectMake (0,0,100,100);`

can i pass any parameter to get it?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can also define a new context for the rect size you want :

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake (0,0,100,100);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Nota : you need to add QuartzCore in import :

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and you can get main view with :

```
UIView *view = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow rootViewController].view
```

Comment: Grabbing the highest level view like this was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you simply want or need to crop your UIImage.

Check out the code in this related question and see if it helps you out:

[How to crop the UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635371/how-to-crop-the-uiimage)

Comment: it is not possible to get the uiimage at certain size?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to capture screen and automatically saved to Image library in iphone device.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```