# Is UIGraphicsBeginImageContext thread safe?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uikit

So I've been under the impression that UIGraphicsBeginImageContext is thread safe, and can be called from any thread to create a new CGContextRef that can be used to draw.

However, the current [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) states that

`"You should call this function from the main thread of your application only."`

However, in the WWDC 2012 session video "Building Concurrent User Interfaces", the speaker shows that you can actually draw in the background, and call that method in the background:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So as you can see, he adds an operation to a `_queue` (which runs on a BG thread), which calls `renderedGraphOfSize`, which calls `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. So what's the deal? I am getting some crashes in my app when it comes to drawing in the background, so I don't know why there are confused examples from Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext definitely is thread safe in iOS 4 and later.
WWDC 2012 session videos relate to iOS 6, so maybe you should relate to iOS 6 documentation as well :)

Answer (score 3):

To quote from the documentation:

> In iOS 4 and later, you may call this function from any thread of your
>   app.

link:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html