# How to replace a region of an image with another image in ios

Tags: ios, uiimage, crop

I want to process a subregion of a UIImage in an iOS app.  Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635371/how-to-crop-the-uiimage), I now have a routine to extract the region in question as a UIImage that I can now manipulate.  Is there a similarly convenient method for placing the region back into the original image?  The alternative I'm considering is a bytewise copy, which seems extremely low-level to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could draw the two images on top of each other, and then combine them to one image.

Assuming you have the original image and the modified part:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalImage.size);

[originalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[modifiedPart drawAtPoint:/* Upper left corner of the modified part */];
UIImage *combined = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

**Edit:**
Forgot this line:

```
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: This approach shows promise, but it is not rotation independent.  The chunks aren't being drawn in the places I'd expect, to put it mildly.

Comment: @mmr: I'm not sure what you mean with rotation independent. When you draw the modified part (which I assume still has the same size) you should provide the same coordinates as you used when chopping it.

Comment: @vaderkvam-- I mean that if I rotate the phone (or simulator), I get extremely strange results.  I'm investigating further, because I may also have gotten my initial code wrong as well.

Comment: @mmr: I see, well that has never happend to me using this code. The combined image behaves - with respect to rotation - the same way as any other image. Anyway good luck with the investigation!

Comment: @vaderkvam-- the rotation problem was upstream.  This code works, thanks!